# Why is Geography is sometimes pejoratively referred to "Advanced Colouring In" as a subject?

Tags: expressions, pejorative-language

Why is Geography is sometimes pejoratively referred to "Advanced Colouring In" as a subject? I have seen people use it as a joke but I don't understand what the joke is about.

Comment: It is a joke. It suggests that geography is not a serious academic subject and not much of an advance on the way in which children use colouring books. It is not really a matter of English language and usage, so I'm voting to close the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a deliberate misunderstanding of the subject, reducing it to maps:

[image: Political map of the United States of America]

Political maps like this are a classical *[four-colour problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem)* akin to a child's colouring book.

Comment: I think you've nailed it, Andrew!  (_Introduction to Coloring in Geography_ (GEO 101) refers to crayons and maps. In _Advanced Coloring in Geography_ (GEO 201), the students only get four crayons.) Either way, geography is a subject that goes well with the activity of coloring, and the phrase as a whole suggests academic credit for a non-academic endeavor, not unlike _Basket Weaving_.

Comment: Geography as a subject as a whole, of course, goes well beyond colouring; it encompasses climate and geology and may even include historical context for the building of settlements. Reducing it to just a colouring exercise because of maps is how it's made the butt of the joke.

Comment: I understood that, too; I didn't bother to reference that part, though, because I thought you had covered that already in your opening statement. But (lest anyone be confused), for the record, you and I agree: it's _Coloring_ that makes the exercise non-academic, **not** _Geography_.

Comment: In _The Road to Wigan Pier_, Orwell says this: "I know that there is not one working-class boy in a thousand who does not pine for the day when he will leave school. He wants to be doing real work, **not wasting his time on ridiculous rubbish like history and geography** [emphasis added]." Read this just last night.